# Chrome Extension Open New Tab on Icon Click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that opens a tab with a specific URL when you click on the icon of the chrome extension. I have tried multiple things so far but I think my syntax may be off a little or something.

for now, I am just trying to open a duplicate window of the window that I am on. This includes getting the URL of the current tab and opening a new tab with that same URL.

this is what I have in my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Linkedin Company Website",
  "version": "0.1",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "logo.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "background":{
    "scripts": ["runwhenclicked.js"]
  }
}
```

my runwhenclicked.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {{
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "get_current_url.js"});
});
```

my get_current_url.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

     // since only one tab should be active and in the current window at once
     // the return variable should only have one entry
     var activeTab = tabs[0];
     chrome.tabs.create({ url: activeTab });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> For now, I am just trying to open a duplicate window of the window
> that I am on. This includes getting the URL of the current tab and
> opening a new tab with that same URL.

This is the easiest way for me

```
/* manifest.json */
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Linkedin Company Website",
  "version": "0.1",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "logo.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "background":{
    "scripts": ["runwhenclicked.js"]
  }
}

/* runwhenclicked.js */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    chrome.tabs.duplicate(tab.id);
});
```